# Configure ActiveMQ Artemis in WildFly 12 to use a PostgreSQL datastore

Tags: postgresql-9.5, activemq-artemis, wildfly-12

I have configured my WildFly 12 instance with a PostgreSQL datastore to use as the journal datastore for ActiveMQ Artemis. However, when WildFly starts up I get the following error:

```
AMQ222010: Critical IO Error, shutting down the server. file=org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.file.JDBCSequentialFile@35d3d246, message=Error attempting to open JDBC file.: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "data" is of type oid but expression is of type bytea
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? My datasource definition is:

```xml
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ActiveMQ-DS" pool-name="ActiveMQ-DS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true" spy="false">
    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/activemq</connection-url>
    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
    <driver>postgresql</driver>
    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>16</max-pool-size>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>amq</user-name>
        <password>amq</password>
     </security>
     <validation>
         <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
         <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
         <background-validation>false</background-validation>
         <background-validation-millis>300000</background-validation-millis>
     </validation>
     <statement>
          <prepared-statement-cache-size>0</prepared-statement-cache-size>
          <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
     </statement>
     <timeout>
          <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
     </timeout>
</datasource>
```

Here is my `messaging-activemq` subsystem configuration:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:3.0">
    <server name="default">
        <journal datasource="ActiveMQ-DS" />
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
        </security-setting>
        <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="jms-virtual" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="jms-virtual" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        </http-connector>
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-connector>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
        </http-acceptor>
        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-acceptor>
        <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
        <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
        <jms-topic name="VideoVaultSync" entries="jms/topic/VideoVaultSync"/>
        <jms-topic name="VICADS-DeviceAlarm" entries="jms/topic/VICADS-DeviceAlarm"/>
        <jms-topic name="VICADS-VideoAlarm" entries="jms/topic/VICADS-VideoAlarm java:jboss/exported/jms/topic/VICADS-VideoAlarm"/>
        <jms-topic name="VICADS-RadarTarget" entries="jms/topic/VICADS-RadarTarget java:jboss/exported/jms/topic/VICADS-RadarTarget"/>
        <jms-topic name="VICADS-AnnunciatorAlarm" entries="jms/topic/VICADS-AnnunciatorAlarm"/>
        <jms-topic name="VICADS-Admin" entries="jms/topic/VICADS-Admin java:jboss/exported/jms/topic/VICADS-Admin"/>
        <jms-topic name="VICADS-VideoSvc" entries="jms/topic/VICADS-VideoSvc java:jboss/exported/jms/topic/VICADS-VideoSvc"/>
        <jms-topic name="VideoVault-SceneAuthentication" entries="jms/topic/VideoVault-SceneAuthentication java:jboss/exported/jms/topic/VideoVault-SceneAuthentication"/>
        <jms-topic name="VICADS-Geometry" entries="jms/topic/VICADS-Geometry java:jboss/exported/jms/topic/VICADS-Geometry"/>
        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
    </server>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: Can you paste the XML config for your messaging subsystem?

Comment: Those are issue being addressed in Apache Artemis

Comment: I've updated my question with the XML config for my messaging subsystem.